# Is it possible to stop my modal from showing every time I redirect from another page to the page where the modal shows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am working on a web app using Node express mongoose and ejs.
I have a modal that shows when a user logs in or signs up and redirects to the dashboard page. The modal is basically a daily motivation quote that's being fetched from an quote API.

Here is my modal that is inside of my dashboard ejs file:

```
<div id="modal-container">
        <div id="modal">
            <h5>✨Motivation of The Day✨</h5>
            <span class="quote"></span>
            <div id="close-btn">close</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is my js that manipulate the DOM:

```
let quote = document.querySelector('.quote')
let closeBtn = document.getElementById('close-btn')
let modalContainer = document.getElementById('modal-container')


window.addEventListener('load', async function() {
    let quotes = []
    const response = await fetch(`https://type.fit/api/quotes`)
    const listOfQuotes = await response.json()
    listOfQuotes.forEach(quote => quotes.push({quote: quote.text, author: quote.author}))

    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)

    quote.innerText = quotes[random].quote
    
    
    closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        modalContainer.style.display = 'none'
    })
    
})
```

the route for this dashboard is /dashboard. Every time I do something like edit a post it takes me to a new page to make the edits and when done I redirect back to the /dashboard route and the modal pops back up again.

how can I make sure the modal only shows once the user logs in/ signs up and only that one time and not every time a user gets redirected to the /dashboard route?

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is happening because you have the modal set to appear every time the window loads and you're not checking if the user has met the condition for the modal to actually appear. The modal appears when the page loads, the user navigates to a different page and, when they return to the /dashboard route, the event listener on window fires again and the modal appears.

You can include a conditional check in the event listener to see if the user is logged in or not and then have the modal's display change based on that value. Basic example below.

HTML:

```
       <body>
         <div>
           <h1>The text below will hide based on "login" state</h1>
           <p class="login-text">The user is logged in</p>
         </div>
       </body>
```

JS:

```
     const isLoggedIn = true;
     const textToHide = document.querySelector(".login-text");

     window.addEventListener("load", () => {

         if (isLoggedIn === false) {
             textToHide.style.display = "none";
         } else {
             textToHide.style.display = "block";
         }})
```

As for handling the state of the user having logged in, you could save that state in `localStorage` or in cookies, depending on your needs.